# Pyspark ML pipeline error when fitting pipeline

Tags: python, pyspark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I have constructed a pipelined from three pyspark.ml.feature (tokenizer,CV,idf)  for the first time all thongs goes well but for the second try it tell me Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o175.fit.
Does any one know what is the cause of this error thanks

```
   import findspark
   findspark.init()
   import pyspark.sql.types as typ
   import pyspark as ps
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import warnings
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
   sparkSession = SparkSession.builder \
       .master("local[2]") \
       .appName("Pyspark Sentiment") \
       .getOrCreate()
   df = sparkSession.read.load('data/Microblog_Trialdata.csv', 
                          format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                          header='true', 
                          inferSchema='true')
df=df.select("sentiment score","spans")
(train_set, val_set, test_set) = df.randomSplit([0.6, 0.2, 0.2], seed = 42)
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer ,CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="spans", outputCol="words")
CV = CountVectorizer(vocabSize=2**11, inputCol="words", outputCol='cv_')
idf = IDF(inputCol='cv_', outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5) #minDocFreq: 

remove sparse terms


#model=CV.fit(data)
    #vo=model.vocabulary 
    #print(type(vo))
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, CV, idf])

    pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(train_set)
    train_df = pipelineFit.transform(train_set)
    val_df = pipelineFit.transform(val_set)
    train_df.select("cv_").show(5,truncate=False)
    train_df.show(5)
```

Comment: You need to give more detail about error. But I guess categorical ids that not seen first time can be caused this error

Comment: Hi hamza i edited the question , sorry i did'nt understand what do you mean by categircal ids exactly ??

Comment: hi jowwel. I added answer can you try.

Answer (score -1):

Words that in train_set but not see in val_set can be cause to error. Count Vectorizer have handleInvalid option to solve this.

```
# this will ignore not seen words
CV = CountVectorizer(vocabSize=2**11, inputCol="words", outputCol='cv_',handleInvalid='skip')
```

Comment: Hamza i tried this but not work it seems there is no parameter handleInvalid for CountVectorizer, the source oferror comes from Pipeline.fit(train_set) before beeing used for val_set

Comment: I faced same problem and solved with this parameter.  My spark versio is 2.3.1. Can you put full error message?

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)